# Is there a disk based nearest neighbour data structure?

Tags: data-structures, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset for which I need to find the K nearest neighbours, or all the neighbours within a distance d. The dataset has a custom distance defined but it is not an Euclidean distance.

I have used [metric trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_trees) before, mostly the cover tree. In this case, however, my dataset is going to be larger than the available memory. So, is there any data structure that can be used for nearest neighbours on a disk stored dataset? A good database index for this operation would also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the cover tree to hold pointers to your disk dataset.  The pointer would contain the relative record number and whatever additional information from the record that allows you to traverse the tree.

Comment: This wouldn't be efficient because the additional information from the record is the whole of the record (think distances between documents or images). I was hoping to minimize disk access, and the cover tree is not specially optimised for this as far as I know.

Comment: I guess I don't understand.  Can't the documents or images be stored on the disk and the index hold the calculated distance and a pointer to the disk location of the document or image?

Comment: I was hoping for something that minimizes the number of disk accesses, because each calculation of the distance requires at least loading one whole document from the database. In practice, the cover tree with your hint performance was satisfactory for my needs.

Comment: why is it **not** a good idea to periodically "write to disk" and "retrieve from disk" some of the dataset ?